# Devise how to redirect to different page (based on some parameter) after sign in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my application, I have two different login forms from two controller which will both sign_in through the Devise::SessionsController, the problem is after successful sign in (or failure) I need to redirect to different pages that specific to the controller. How can I do this. I currently have this in my Devise::SessionsController, which

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    def create
        resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
        return sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
      end

      def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, resource=nil)
        scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
        resource ||= resource_or_scope
        sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource
        redirect_to dashboard_path
      end

      def failure      
        redirect_to index_path
      end
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In application controller

```
  before_filter :store_location
  def store_location
    unless params[:controller] == "devise/sessions"
      url = #calculate the url here based on a params[:token] which you passed in
      session[:user_return_to] = url
    end
  end

  def stored_location_for(resource_or_scope)
    session[:user_return_to] || super
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still looking for a work around. I was able to solve this by:

First, create a Sessions controller inheriting from `Devise::SessionsController`

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def new
    get_pre_login_url(request.referer)
    super
  end

  def create
    @@referer_url
    super
  end

private

  def get_pre_login_url(url)
    @@referer_url = url
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    # @@referer_url
    sign_in_url = url_for(:action => 'new', :controller => 'sessions', :only_path => false, :protocol => 'http')
    if @@referer_url == sign_in_url
      super
    else
      stored_location_for(resource) || @@referer_url || root_path
    end
  end

end
```

You'll notice I'm setting a class variable (`@@variable_name`), which I'm not keen on, but this is what I came up with after 4 hours of trying various other ways of solving this. I'm also trying to be careful not to screw with Devise's controller too much and using `super` and only including the actions I care about.

Next, in routes you can now point Devise's defaults to the Controller above. You don't need it exactly like below for the `devise_for`, just the part referencing the `controllers: { sessions: "sessions" }`

```
MyPortfolio::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, path_names: { sign_in: "login",
                                   sign_out: "logout" },
                    controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks",
                                   sessions: "sessions" }

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :projects do
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :users

  root :to => 'home#index'

  get 'login' => 'devise/sessions#new'
  get 'about_me' => 'about#index'
end
```

It might not be the DRYest solution around, but it was the only one that I was able to come up with to point the redirect back to the page of origin instead of root or an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by defining `after_sign_in_path_for` method in your controller, where you want to customize this redirect path.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is how can I provide parameters in the after_sign_in_path_for to tell where to go next?

Comment: Than you should create your own sessions controller and override it in devise configuration, like this: `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "users/sessions" }`. In this controller you can pass optional params to `after_sign_in_path_for`, and check them later when its needed. Also, you can pass aditional params to session and check session vars in customized `after_sign_in_path_for`, or you can use `Thread.current` to pass this additional param.

Comment: Thank you Hck, I guess the problem really is how should I define this parameter and where should I pass in this parameter to after_sign_in_path, please help.

Answer (score 0):

The following is more global solution but it can be used in your case.
It uses attr_accessor. No extra params to `after_sign_in_path_for` action and no class variable required.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :redirect_to
end
```

Then, with a dedicated sessions_controller file (override as recommended by Devise), copy-paste [the original devise action](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L18) and add the line `resource.redirect_to = sign_in_params[:redirect_to]` before respond_with.
Add the new redirect to the `after_sign_in_path_for` action and add the `:redirect_to` params to devise allowed signin params.

```
# app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb

class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_filter :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]
  
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)

    # set redirect_to
    resource.redirect_to = sign_in_params[:redirect_to]

    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

  # set url to redirect_to url if present
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    return resource_or_scope.redirect_to if resource_or_scope.redirect_to.present? && !resource_or_scope.respond_to?(:devise_scope)
    stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || signed_in_root_path(resource_or_scope)
  end

  # add redirect_to to devise signin allowed params
  def configure_sign_in_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << :redirect_to
  end

end
```

Finally, update your view to set a hidden param for the `redirect_to` url

```
# app/views/users/sessions/new.html.haml
# from params in url
<% if (param_redirect_to = params[:redirect_to]).present?
  <%= f.hidden_field :redirect_to, value: param_redirect_to %>
<% end %>
# or hardcoded if you have 2 sign-in forms
<%= f.hidden_field :redirect_to, value: 'your custom redirect url' %>
```

`GET http://localhost:3000/login?redirect_to=www.test.com` will redirect your user to [www.test.com](http://www.test.com) after successful signing