# ruby rails - redirect to original request url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is what I have for redirecting to a default url(myapp_url). But I want to change redirect to go the request url was entered by the user after authentication. 
How do I do that? I tried couple of options from searching here, like :back. But no go.

User enters an url, if not authenticated then gets redirected to the login page, then after login user shall be redirected to the original request url.

```
def create
   user = User.Authenticate(params[:user_id], params[:password])
 if user
   session[:user_id] = user.id
   redirect_to myapp_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
else
    flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
    render "new"
  end

end
```

Comment: This solution worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835365/devise-how-to-redirect-to-different-page-based-on-some-parameter-after-sign-in

Answer (score 16):

You can read [the chapter about "Friendly forwarding"](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/_single-page#sec-friendly_forwarding) in the "Ruby on Rails Tutorial" by Michael Hartl to see how you can easily implement it.

Basically you have 3 helper methods:

1. `store_location` to store the user desired location in the session
2. `redirect_back_or(url)` redirect the user to the location stored in the session or, if not set, to the location contained in the `url` method param
3. and `clear_return_to` used "internally" by the `redirect_back_or` method to clear this piece of information once used

And then you use these methods:

A) when you see a guest user try to access a page that needs authentication use `store_location` before redirect him to the login page.
 B) when a user is logged in, you use `redirect_back_or(url)` to redirect him to the right location (if present of course)

This is an overview of how this work, you get the idea but I suggest to read that chapter for the implementation (few) details.

Comment: Can this be implemented with a post request? Say you are submitting a form and the session expired before submission. Michael Hartles example would cause a routing error. I think Rails will attempt a get request after signing in. For example, say you have `Posts` and `comments`, where comments are nested under posts, and comment submissions happen from the Posts#show. The resulting URL after logging in would be `app.com/posts/1/comments` causing a routing error, which would not be the case if the request were a POST one.

Comment: Redirects are sent by the browser as GET requests. Even if you got the browser to redirect as POST, the original form submission data would not be provided.

Comment: The tutorial link in the answer is dead, here's an updated link: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/_single-page#sec-friendly_forwarding

Answer (score 1):

You need to save path in session before redirection on authentication, and after successful auth redirect to this path.

Comment: I tried this, but no luck. `session[:return_to] ||= request.referer` `redirect_to session[:return_to]`