# How can I capture a return URL before a redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 application I have a before action called `Authorize` which will redirect the user to a login page if they are not logged in.

Is it possible to capture the current controller and method fired before the redirect is initiated by the Before Action?

*ApplicationController.rb*:

```
def authorize
  unless User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    redirect_to login_url, notice: "Please log in"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `request.referer` but this doesn't always work. For perfect solution refer this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10056022/1377943